# Как правильно "разделять" приложение на слои?

Tags: c#, архитектура, проектирование, инспекция-кода

В своих приложениях я использую подход разделение функционала на *слои*, слои я стараюсь *группировать* на основании функциональности

- *Data Access Object*
- *Data Access Layer*
- *Business Logic Layer*
- *GUI*

Для работы с бд я использую [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework). Довольно часто я стал ловить себя на мысли что я ***не понимаю/не уверен*** на каком из слоев должна быть реализована та или иная *функциональность*.

Например: необходимо получить список объектов из бд, пусть класс будет называться `Request`, тогда я делаю так:

В *DAL* у меня есть `generic` репозиторий() c реализацией `CRUD` и торчащим наружу свойством `protected virtual IQueryable<T> Entities{...}`

В *BLL* я обращаюсь к свойству `Entities` *вытягиваю* из бд необходимые мне данные, *материализую*(`ToList()`,`Single()`), преобразую в *DTO* объекты которые отдаю в *GUI*.

В целом меня такой подход устраивал всем, базовые методы(`CRUD`) реализованы в одном классе реализующим `generic` репозиторий, методы для работы с конкретными сущностями реализованы в слое `BLL`.

Но тут наступил переломный момент: мне понадобилось использовать *хранимые процедуры/функции*.

Для поддержания *чистоты* приложения доступ к *хранимкам* хочу(мне так кажется правильней) сделать в слое *DAL* я это представляю как то так :

Сделать `IRequestRepository` в который в качестве зависимости передать `generic` репозиторий плюс реализовать необходимые методы/функции, например такие как обращение и получения результата *хранимой функции*, так же мне будет необходимо *выставить* наружу в `generic` репозитории `DbContext` что бы можно было обращаться к *хранимкам*(`_context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(...)`), дальше же все остается так как и было.

как альтернатива отказаться от `generic` репозитория и для каждого необходимого класса из *DAO* реализовать класс репозитория, но в этом случае в каждом классе будет дублирование *CRUD* методов, что мне кажется не правильным.

---

Пример реализации:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{

    T GetById(object id);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Insert(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Update(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
    DbContext Context { get; }
}

public interface IRequestRepository
{
    Request GetById(object id);

    void Insert(Request request);
    void Insert(IEnumerable<Request> requests);
    void Update(Request request);
    void Update(IEnumerable<Request> requests);
    void Delete(Request request);
    void Delete(IEnumerable<Request> requests);
}

public class RequestRepository: IRequestRepository
{
    private readonly IRepository<Request> _requestRepository;

    public RequestRepository(IRepository<Request> requestRepository)
    {
        this._requestRepository = requestRepository;
    }

    #region Методы обертки над методами из IRepository
    Request GetById(object id) {...}
    void Insert(Request request) {...}
    void Insert(IEnumerable<Request> requests) {...}
    void Update(Request request) {...}
    void Update(IEnumerable<Request> requests) {...}
    void Delete(Request request) {...}
    void Delete(IEnumerable<Request> requests) {...}
    #endregion

    #region Методы обертки над хранимыми функциями/процедурами
    IEnumerable<Request> GetListOfActiveRequests()
    {
        var _requestList = _requestRepository.Context.Database
            .SqlQuery<Request>("Select * from dbo.GetListOfActiveRequests()");
        //...
    }
    #endregion

    //Прочие методы

}
```

Как все таки *лучше/правильней* поступить в описанном мной случае?

---

**UPD:**

исходя из ответа @PavelMayorov, если я правильно понял структура классов у меня вырисовывается следующим образом

```
public interface IRequestRepository
{
    #region CRUD методы
    Request GetById(object id);
    void Insert(Request request);
    void Insert(IEnumerable<Request> requests);
    void Update(Request request);
    void Update(IEnumerable<Request> requests);
    void Delete(Request request);
    void Delete(IEnumerable<Request> requests);
    #endregion  
}

public interface IRequestHistoryRepository
{
    #region CRUD методы
    #endregion
}

public class RequestRepository: IRequestRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public RequestRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this._context=context;
    }

    // Реализация необходимых методов
    // для работы с "сущностью"
}

public class RequestHistoryRepository: IRequestHistoryRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public RequestHistoryRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this._context=context;
    }

    // Реализация необходимых методов
    // для работы с "сущностью"
}
```

вот только в этом случае будет дублирование в каждом таком репозитории кода *CRUD*

```
try
{
    if (request == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    //Создание/Чтение/Редактирование/Удаление
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
    var msg = string.Empty;

    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            msg += string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage) + Environment.NewLine;

    var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
    //Debug.WriteLine(fail.Message, fail);
    throw fail;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Репозиторий со свойством `IQueryable<T> Entities` - это безусловно лишняя сущность - EF уже сама по себе предоставляет неплохую реализацию репозитория (`DbSet<T>`). Особенно лишними являются generic-репозитории.

Вообще говоря, в простых программах слоем DAL можно считать саму библиотеку EF; делать поверх новый слой - странное занятие. Если ваша программа достаточно простая - то просто выкиньте из нее все репозитории и увидите как все стало проще :)

---

Основная проблема слоев DAL в типичных программах - потеря инкапсуляции, схема хранения напрямую связана с внешним интерфейсом из-за использования типов модели хранения в интерфейсах.

Если вам действительно нужен отдельный слой DAL - предлагаю вам выкинуть из его интерфейсов все упоминания моделей EF. Хранение данных должно быть полностью скрыто в слое DAL, никаких классов-сущностей или `IQueryable<>` наружу торчать не должно. Код уровня бизнес-логики не должен знать, простой ли запрос идет к базе - или же вызывается хранимая процедура.

---

Что же до повторяющегося кода - есть стандартные способы борьбы с ним: методы-хелперы, базовые классы, AOP.

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: IQueryable то чем не угодил? Он всего лишь признак, что это ленивый запрос, данных ещё нет.

Comment: @Monk просто у него нет смысла, вот и все

Answer (score 0):

Не существует идеального готового архитектурного решения на все случаи жизни. Мне неизвестны программисты, которые с самого начала своей карьеры, реализовывали бы хорошие и удобные слоения приложений.

Поскольку речь идет об объектно-ориентированном языке программирования C#, то я бы предложил автору вопроса хотя бы в первом приближении ознакомиться с соответствующими приемами и шаблонами проектирования и разработки и попытаться взять их на вооружение.

Классический учебник на эту тему в русском переводе называется "Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования", авторы Э.Гамма, Р.Хелм, Р.Джонсон, Д.Влиссидес.

На самом деле на эту же тему и именно о C# есть более читабельная книга. Авторы Р.Мартин и М.Мартин, а называется она "Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#".

Сразу скажу что прочтение вышеозначенной литературы не сделает никого мгновенно готовым архитектором.

Comment: на текущий момент я не преследую целей стать супер архитектором, указанная вами книга(банды четырех) у меня есть. но довольно часто *высокореповые* участники сообщетсва рекомендуют не торопиться с её чтением дабы не сделать хуже: использовать патерны всегда и всюду

Comment: Простите пожалуйста, я вас похоже неправильно понял. Мне показалось что вас как раз беспокоит "непонимание/неуверенность" в правильности выбираемых вами способов декомпозиции поведения вашего приложения. Я счел это как раз проявлением потребности развития архитектурных навыков. Если это не так, то конечно нет никакого смысла осваивать новые знания и ломать голову над техническими текстами. Тем более что я не знаю пока ни одного человека, который сказал бы что разбираться с "Паттернами" было легко и незатейливо.

Comment: у меня есть поверхностные знания о патернах проектирования(как минимум об их существовании), но я стараюсь к ним не прибегать потому что грань между облегчением структуры и усложнением её же слишком *тонка*. проще говоря боюсь сделать хуже. спасибо за ответ